# URL Rewrite works with redirect but not rewrite

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-8, url-rewrite-module

I set up an IIS server (IIS 8) and added URL Rewrite.

If I set:

```
Requested URL: "Matches the Pattern"
Using: "Regular Expressions"
Pattern: "(.*)"
No conditions
Action Type: "Redirect"
Redirect URL: "http://myloadbalancer_censored_name.elb.amazonaws.com/"
Redirect Type: "Temporary (307)"
```

This works the way I would expect.

When I type the url in my browser (something like "http://10.0.1.47") my browser's omnibar changes to the redirect URL (something like http://myloadbalancer_censored_name.elb.amazonaws.com/).

So far so good ...

But when I change the setting in URL Rewrite from redirect to rewrite, I get back:

```
HTTP Error 404.4 - Not Found

Requested URL
   http://10.0.1.47:80/ 

Physical Path
   C:\inetpub\wwwroot
```

I'm trying to set up a reverse proxy to pull web resources as if they came from a separate machine (to hide the internals of where my web app server actually lives).

**EDIT:**

In the IIS log I can see these 2 lines:

```
2016-04-06 15:59:34 10.0.1.11 GET / - 80 - 10.0.1.11 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - 404 4 123 15

2016-04-06 16:01:07 10.0.1.11 GET / - 80 - 10.0.1.11 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - 307 0 0 46
```

The first one is with rewrite. The second one is with redirect. This shows I am hitting the same IP, but it fails with rewrites for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the root level server in Internet Information Manager (IIS) and select Application Request Routing Cache.

Click “Server Proxy Settings …” on the right most pane.

Check “Enable Proxy”.